# 2 level Wrapper class not working in wizard

Tags: controller, wrapper-class

I have a custom object Package__c which has various products(Product2 object) attached to it. On first page of wizard, user can enter quantity for Packages and then proceed to next page where he can select products for the packages. Since Quantity for Packages and Selection for Products will be dynamic I have created two wrapper classes, PkgWrapper and ProdWrapper with PkgWrapper encapasulating ProdWrapper. However on going back and forth between the two pages,selection of products done for packages is not respected and flag status is not saved.
Can anyone help.

Here are two visualforce pages:
**Config1**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="true" standardController="Opportunity" extensions="ConfigController">
<apex:form >
     <apex:pageBlock title="Package List">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pkgList}" var="pkg">
            <apex:column value="{!pkg.selectedPkg.Name__c}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Quantity" ><apex:inputText value="{!pkg.quantity}"/></apex:column>
       </apex:pageBlockTable>
       <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
           <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!navigatePage2}"/>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>
     </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Config2**

```
    <apex:page showHeader="true" standardController="Opportunity" extensions="ConfigController" tabStyle="Quote" >
<apex:form >
<apex:panelBar items="{!pkgList}" var="pkg">
   <apex:panelBarItem label="{!pkg.selectedPkg.Name__c}"  headerClassActive="headerActive" headerClass="header" contentClass="body" expanded="false" >
          <apex:pageBlock title="Products">
           <apex:dataTable value="{!pkg.prods}" var="prod" width="80%" cellpadding="6" style="float:left;border-collapse:separate;margin-right:20px;">
               <apex:column > <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!prod.theSelected}"/> </apex:column>
               <apex:column value="{!prod.product.Name}" />
           </apex:dataTable>
       </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:panelBarItem>
</apex:panelBar>
<apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!navigatePage1}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller class**

```
    global class ConfigController {
    public List<PkgWrapper> pkgList{get;set;}
    public ConfigController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
       List<Product_Package__c> packList = [Select Id,Name__c,(Select Id,Name FROM Products__r) from Product_Package__c LIMIT 2];
           pkgList = new List<PkgWrapper>();
           for(Product_Package__c p : packList){
               pkgList.add(new PkgWrapper(p));
           }
     }
    public class PkgWrapper {
        public Integer quantity{get;set;}
        public Product_Package__c selectedPkg{get;set;}
        public List<ProdWrapper> prods{get;set;}

        public PkgWrapper(Product_Package__c pkg)
        {
            selectedPkg=pkg;
            quantity=1;
            prods = new List<ProdWrapper>();

            for(Product2 prod : selectedPkg.Products__r){
                  prods.add(new ProdWrapper(prod));  
            }
        }
    }
    public class ProdWrapper{
        public Boolean theSelected{get;set;}
        public Product2 product{get;set;}

        public ProdWrapper(Product2 prod){
            theSelected = false;
            product = prod;
        }
    }
    public PageReference navigatePage1() {
        return (new PageReference('/apex/config1'));
    }
    public PageReference navigatePage2() {
        return (new PageReference('/apex/config2'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong; the constructor should only run on the first page and not when the view state is used to recreate the controller for the second page. Can you confirm that both the `quantity` and the `theSelected` inputs are lost?

Comment: Try using Page.config1 and Page.config2 instead of the URL fragment. It might be triggering a redirect with state clearing.

Comment: @KeithC 'quantity' is saved but 'theSelected' is lost.

Comment: @sfdcfox no luck using Page.Config1 and Page.Config2 either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears related to using `apex:panelBar`/`apex:panelBarItem`.

If you replace:

```
<apex:panelBar items="{!pkgList}" var="pkg">
```

with:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!pkgList}" var="pkg">
```

and delete the `apex:panelBarItem` the `selected` state is preserved.

Googling may reveal more explanation or a work-around. If you can use some other `apex:...` tag do; you could also roll your own show/hide JavaScript if that is important.